# Spring with Kotlin & Jackson deserialization: lateinit property <attribute> has not been initialized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I have to admit that I'm quite new to Kotlin and a complete newbie with Spring, but those are the tools that I have to use, so here I am.

I have a custom `Jackson` Deserializer which needs an instance of an externally (`Spring Boot` properties file) configured class in order to do its work, but despite my attempts, I always get the following error:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property cordaRPC has not been initialized`

I really don't know how to proceed due to the pseudo-automatic Spring stuffs… I think it may be that the Jackson instrumentation happens before the configuration of the property's class, but I'll wait for your help.

---

In order to provide some context, here are some of the prototyped work:

The error source is the `cordaRPC` in `DumpDataDeserializer.kt`.

**File: CordaGateway.kt:**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "corda.rpc")
class CordaGateway(@Value("\${$CORDA_NODE_HOST_ADDRESS}") private val host: String,
                   @Value("\${$CORDA_NODE_RPC_PORT}") private val port: Int,
                   @Value("\${$CORDA_NODE_RPC_USERNAME}") private val username: String,
                   @Value("\${$CORDA_NODE_RPC_PASSWORD}") private val password: String)
    : AutoCloseable
{
    lateinit var rpcConnection: CordaRPCConnection
    lateinit var proxy: CordaRPCOps

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CordaGateway::class.java)

    @PostConstruct
    fun initialiseNodeRPCConnection() {
        val rpcAddress = NetworkHostAndPort(host, port)
        val rpcClient = CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress)
        val rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password)
        proxy = rpcConnection.proxy
    }

    @PreDestroy
    override fun close() {
        rpcConnection.notifyServerAndClose()
    }
}
```

**File: DumpData.kt:**

```
// Untouchable external class
import net.corda.core.identity.Party

data class DumpData(val value: Int, val test: String, val user: Party)
```

**File: DumpDataDeserializer.kt**

```
class DumpDataDeserializer(vc: Class<*>? = null) : StdDeserializer<DumpData>(vc) {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController::class.java)

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var cordaRPC: CordaGateway

    override fun deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): DumpData {
        val node: JsonNode = jp.codec.readTree(jp)

        val value = node.get("value").intValue()
        val editedTest = node.get("test").textValue().plus(" edited!")
        val userName = node.get("user").textValue()

        val party = cordaRPC.proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(CordaX500Name.parse(userName))!!    

        return DumpData(value, editedTest, party)
    }
}
```

**File: CustomJsonConfig.kt:**

```
@Configuration
class CustomJsonConfig {
    @Bean
    fun prova(): Module {
        return SimpleModule().addDeserializer(DumpData::class.java, DumpDataDeserializer())
    }
}
```

The deserialization is invoked as follow:

```
val data = objMapper.treeToValue(body.get("prova"), DumpData::class.java)
```

---

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check that the input JSON actually has a value for the `cordaRPC` field?

Comment: cordaRPC isn't a JSON field… is a "static" helper instance to be used in order to deserialize part of the JSON.

Comment: Then this field is never injected, or at least not in time.

Comment: And how can I inject it ?

Comment: You are manually constructing `DumpDataDeserializer` in `CustomJsonConfig` so you need to inject it at that point. You have your `CordaGateway` class annotated as `Component` so Spring will make that available to you elsewhere (e.g. as a constructor parameter). So you could add a constructor parameter to `CustomJsonConfig` which takes in a `CordaGateway` object, make it a private member variable of that class, and then pass that to `DumpDataDeserializer` when you construct it in the `prova` method. You could also change it from a `lateinit var` to a constructor parameter too if you like.

Comment: Thanks @YoniGibbs, that is exactly how I managed to solve it in the mean time… I left the question open in order to see if there is a better, Spring-like, way. :)